# Can I join a prometheus query to a postgres query to get metadata?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a prometheus query that returns time series data along with a single label that I've grouped by:

```
sum by(object_id) (increase(my_metric[$__rate_interval])) != 0
```

I have this visualized in a pie chart, but I'd like to display the object's name instead of the id. I have a config table in postgres with `id,name` which I can run in another query, but I don't see a way to join the two. Since the prometheus query is a time series, the label `object_id` is kind of considered as a column. So when I try to do `join by field`, each of the values of `object_id` shows up as a field.

To be clear, what I'd like as the end result is a pie chart showing the name of the object, either in the pie chart itself or in the legend of the pie chart.

Comment: Pie chart doesn't visualize a time dimension, so why your Promql query returns a time series? Return just single number per object and then join transformation will be enough.

Comment: To clarify what Jan means: under your prometheus query select type _Instant_ and _Table_. Also for grafana's join to work your query must return column with the same name, so use alias for column `id`.

Comment: We have the pie chart configured to Total as it's reducer function. But you bring up a good point, if I have a meter that is counting something. Is there a prometheus query that can just give me the total over the last X time per label value, without returning a time series?

Comment: Why are you using Total over query with increase? What exactly are trying to visualize?

Comment: The number of items added to a queue (represented by a meter) per object_id (a label) over X amount of time. Visualized as a pie chart with the name of the object available for tooltip/legend by looking up the object_id against config.